# compiling with /NODEFAULTLIB

Tags: c++, c

testing my program that I compiled with VC10 /MT on a clean install of windows XP SP2 gives me this error: "This application has failed to start because MSVCRXXX.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem." How do I make my program compatible with this version of windows besides obviously shipping the dll with my program (which I really do not want to do). I know the problem is this particular OS version doesn't ship with MSVCR100.dll but isn't compiling with /MT supposed to fix that? It doesn't work on windows 7 either. Why is the compiler ignoring my /MT flag?!

Comment: Are you sure that this option is set for ***all*** projects in your solution, *and* for any other 3rd party libraries that you link in? And are you sure that you're setting the /MT switch for the "Release" build *and* trying to run the same build on the XP machine?

Comment: Can you use `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS foo.exe` on each of your binaries? This will tell you which binary still depends on the .dll runtime.

Comment: Yes, I made sure I was setting the right configuration profile. That's the first thing I did. I found that the problem is I'm using /NODEFAULTLIB but I am statically linking msvcrt.lib. How do I make my program work with /NODEFAULTLIB on other computers? it works with default libs

Comment: If you statically link correctly, there should be no dependency on the .dll version of the CRT.  Is your program using 3rd party libraries that depend on the .dll CRT?

Comment: [DependecyWalker](http://dependencywalker.com) may help.

Comment: I was using 1 third party library but I removed it and it's still not working.

Comment: `I am statically linking msvcrt.lib` That's the import library for the `MSVCR*.DLL`. The static CRT lib would be `libcmt.lib` instead.

Comment: Actually, there was one more but I removed it and it's still not working. The libs I'm using: taskschd.lib, comsupp.lib, ws2_32.lib, msvcrt.lib & the inherited ones.

Comment: yes adding libcmt.lib in place of msvcrt.lib fixed the problem. Also I found a mini CRT on the web but I can't use it because of some other lib I'm using that requires the main one. I also fixed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit the relevant information into the post, not in the comments.

> Why is the compiler ignoring my /MT flag?!

Because you are telling the linker to ignore the default libraries (`/NODEFAULTLIB`) and link `msvcrt.lib` instead, which is the import library for the `DLL` version of the CRT.

- Either drop the `/NODEFAULTLIB`, remove the `msvcrt.lib` and let the compiler/linker do the job.
- Or change `msvcrt[d].lib` to `libcmt[d].lib`.